# Codeigniter: index.php? is removed when back button is pressed

Tags: codeigniter

My default page URL when I logged in looks like this:

*http://localhost/project/index.php?/home*

but when I press back button, the index.php? was removed and it became:

*http://localhost/project/home*

This results in error:

> 404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0

I need help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: can your problem is solved or not?

Comment: remove `.htaccess` file or `RewriteEngine` Off then check?

Answer (score 1):

go to config.php file.
And change
FROM
$config['base_url']='http://localhost/project/';
TO
$config['base_url']='http://localhost/project/index.php?/';